# Rails Rspec error - undefined method `visit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, bdd

So I'm new to TDD & I'm throwing some Rspec errors here on my tests...Basically after running bundle exec rspec spec, I get an `undefined method 'visit'` error on some of my specs. Any help on how to make these tests pass would be much appreciated:  Thanks.

```
Failures:

1) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for # <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007ffda8049540>
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007ffda4f3ac38>
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) User pages signup page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007ffda8262e58>
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) User pages signup page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007ffda82663c8>
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 9.08 seconds
24 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19 # User pages signup page
```

My spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } # Code to make a user variable
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
  end
end
```

And my spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

before do
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                  password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end

subject { @user }

it { should respond_to(:name) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }
it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
it { should respond_to(:password) }
it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

it { should be_valid }

describe "when name is not present" do
  before { @user.name = " " }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when email is not present" do
  before { @user.email = " " }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when name is too long" do
  before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when email format is invalid" do
  it "should be invalid" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                   foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      @user.should_not be_valid
    end      
  end
end

describe "when email format is valid" do
  it "should be valid" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
    addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      @user.should be_valid
    end      
  end
end

describe "when email address is already taken" do
  before do
    user_with_same_email = @user.dup
    user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
    user_with_same_email.save
  end
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password is not present" do
  before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "with a password that's too short" do
  before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
  it { should be_invalid }
end

describe "return value of authenticate method" do
  before { @user.save }
  let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

  describe "with valid password" do
    it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
  end

  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
  end
end 

describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
  before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
  before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

end
```

And lastly my views/users/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

and views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
```

& I've added my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Also getting this new error now after fixing as per Billy's solution

```
Failures:

1) User pages signup page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find css "title" with text "Sign up" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
 # ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find css "title" with text "Michael Hartl" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
 # ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 9.41 seconds
24 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:19 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
```

You put the Capybara integration tests in `requests` folder. That's why the method `visit` won't work.

To fix, just move all the tests from  `spec/requests` to  `spec/features`.

Comment: @BB500, you need to create that folder manually. You can even create sub folders under it such as  `spec/features/models`.

Comment: @BB500, please note the `/features` folder is only intended for integration tests which will use Capybara. For other functional tests such as model, controller, helpers etc, you don't need move them, and they won't need Capybara DSL such as `visit`.

Comment: Thanks man! - I moved that test file to a new features folder & those tests passed.  (of course now i've got a couple new ones...maybe you can spot whats going on here as well??) I've edited the post.

Comment: @BB500, nice you fixed. And then welcome to TDD world. The errors you showed next are your best friends in TDD, along with your fixing them, you build the feature. If no `title`, supply the title, then, if anything need, supply it until test passed!

Answer (score 20):

This happens because you are trying to use the `visit` method from `Capybara::DSL`.
If you check the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec):

```
 Capybara is no longer supported in
 request specs as of Capybara 2.0.0. The recommended way to use Capybara is
 with feature specs.
```

To solve this problem you should move your tests to `spec/features` folder or include `Capybara::DSL` for the request specs:

```
#spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  config.include Capybara::DSL, :type => :request
```

Comment: thanks man - appreciate the help. (apparently i don't have enough reputation to "up" an answer

Comment: Included Capybara in the Rspec help file instead of adding a new folder. Worked! +1